# Converting between AccountId32 and AccountId in Substrate

Tags: blockchain, parity, substrate, polkadot

I have a requirement where i get passed in some bytes and i need to create an accountId from it in Substrate 2.0.

Is there a way to convert between `AccountId32` and `<T as frame_system::Trait>::AccountId` in the runtime (FRAME) ? Or to create an instance of `<T as frame_system::Trait>::AccountId` from bytes?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given raw bytes, you can attempt to construct an account id like so:

```
T::AccountId::decode(&mut &bytes[..]).unwrap_or_default();
```

You may want to handle your error condition differently than returning a default AccountId.

If you can verify that your raw bytes has length 32 (`[u8; 32]`), this operation should never fail, so you could place an `.expect("32 bytes can always construct an AccountId32")`.

Comment: If i could up vote by a million i would have. Thank you so much for this. It worked like a charm.

Comment: is there any way to convert AccountId32 to AccountId